# How to emulate lodash .find method in a Express app with Array.prototype.filter method

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

I am working through a [great course learning API design with Express](https://frontendmasters.com/courses/api-design-nodejs/).

```
app.get('/lions/:id', function(req, res){
  var lion = _.find(lions, {id: req.params.id});
  res.json(lion || {});
});
```

Anyway I noticed the instructor used lodash for some data manipulations and tried to take a stab at doing the same with the vanilla [Array.prototype.filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control)

```
app.get('/lions/:id', function(req, res){
  var lion = lions.filter(function(id){ 
    return {id: req.params.id}
  });
  res.json(lion || {});
});
```

I just get back an empty array...`[]`

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: FYI [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=control) is a native method as well.

Comment: @pawel Oui! Thanks my friend!

Comment: A good way to learn how a popular library works is to see it's source code. Here is lodash's [`find`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.4/lodash.js#L9229)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The **FIND** method gets the very first element that meets the expression as TRUE. **FILTER** will return any item that meets the expression as TRUE.

```
app.get('/lions/:id', function(req, res){
  var lion = lions.filter(function(id){ 
    return id === req.params.id;
  });
  res.json(lion || {});
});
```

> A polyfill exists for older browsers for the Native JS **FIND** method.
>   [FIND Polyfill Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example)
>
> How **Filter** method works...

```
var numbers = [9,3,5,0,-1];

var result = numbers.filter(function(num){
  return num;
});

// result => [9,3,5,-1]; zero is falsey.
// Filter does not return the actual number, only if the result is truthey.
```

** UPDATE **

```
// So returning something like **{id: req.params.id}** is always truthy
// because an object is true !!{} === true; => TRUE.
// Even if {id: undefined};
// Also, note that the filter function passed everything into the new array that was truthy,
// which is NOT what **FIND** does.
```

> Note the triple (===) is just how I do any comparison now as per 
>   [Equality Comparison (STRICT)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

In the original answer I was incorrect in the way your data is arranged. Also, if you want to actually build your own **FIND** method, which is perhaps more of what you were asking, then the following example would work.

```
var lions = [{id: 2, name: "blue"}, {id: 4, name: "green"}, {id:8, name: "red"}, {id: 2, name: "yellow"}];


app.get('/lions/:id', function(req, res){
  res.json(lions[lions.map(ids).indexOf(req.params.id)] || {});
});

// Helper Functions

function ids(lion){
  return lion.id;
}
```

Comment: @SoExPz I am confused. In filter wouldn't saying `return lion.id == req.params.id` be sufficient because when you'd go to the param of the route and enter a number it would just return that object that ID? Or the empty object if not found....

Comment: Thanks so much @SoEzPz!

Answer (score 2):

```
app.get('/lions/:id', function(req, res) {
    var lion = lions.filter(function(lion) {
        return lion.id == req.params.id
    });
    res.json(lion || {});
});
```

Comment: I think to fully emulate `find` using `filter` you'd need to return `lion[0]`, because filter would return an array, not the first element that passes the test.